# NSMutableArray addObject is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, null

I am new to iOS dev,here is my first app-calculator,
But the NSMuteableArray "_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate" always be "nil",I don't know what to do???

Here is the interface

```
@interface demoViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *valueString;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *numberArrayWaitingForCalculate;
@end
```

here is the implement 1

```
@implementation demoViewController
@synthesize numberArrayWaitingForCalculate=_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate;

- (NSMutableArray *)numberWaitingForCalculate
{
    if(!_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate)
        _numberArrayWaitingForCalculate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    return _numberArrayWaitingForCalculate;
}
```

here is the tapNumber method

```
- (IBAction)tapNumber:(UIButton *)numberButton {
    if(LastButtonWasMode)
    {
        _valueString=@"";
        LastButtonWasMode=NO;
    }

    NSString *numberAsString = numberButton.currentTitle;
    _valueString=[_valueString stringByAppendingString:numberAsString];
    result.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_valueString];
    }
```

here is tapPlus method

```
- (IBAction)tapPlus:(id)sender {
    [_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_valueString intValue]]];
    resultOfAllNumberInputBefore +=[_valueString intValue];
   [self setMode:1];
```

}

Comment: Using lazy initialization for an instance variable that points to an array is pointless and, as you've discovered, fragile.   Just initialize the array in your designated initializer and be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line should be using the property and not the instance variable. i.e. you're not actually calling the getter that allocates the array.

Change this line:

```
[_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_valueString intValue]]];
```

to:

```
[self.numberArrayWaitingForCalculate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_valueString intValue]]];
```

Comment: After I use "self.numberArrayWaitingForCalculate" instead of "_numberArrayWatingForCalculate",there isn't "numberArrayWaitingForCalculate"object when I debug,it's empty.

Comment: when I use"_numberArrayWatingForCalculate",I can got the "numberArrayWaitingForCalculate"object when debug,through it's "nil"

Comment: Thats because when using the self.numberArrayWaitingForCalcuate, the instance variable is called _numberArrayWaitingForCalculate (unless you assign it to something else). Long story short, bbum is spot on. There's no benefit for overriding the getter on that array since you don't do any custom initialization. Just use the standard getter. Then bam, done.

Answer (score 3):

You created a getter that "lazy loads" the mutable array (meaning that you create it if it doesn't exist already. That's a valid approach.

However, if you do that, you need to ALWAYS use the getter. You're using the iVar directly (_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate). Don't do that. Replace all instances of "_numberArrayWaitingForCalculate" with `[self numberArrayWaitingForCalculate]` except in the implementation of your getters/setters and probably your dealloc method.

So your tapPlus method should read:

```
- (IBAction)tapPlus:(id)sender 
{
    [[self numberArrayWaitingForCalculate] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_valueString intValue]]];
    resultOfAllNumberInputBefore +=[_valueString intValue];
   [self setMode:1];
}
```

EDIT:

By the way, for something as lightweight as an empty mutable array, I think I would take a different approach. Rather than lazy-loading the array in a getter, I would create an init method for my class that created an empty mutable array and installed it in the iVar.

Objects like view controllers can be initialized more than one way. It might get initialized with `initWithNibName:bundle:` or with `initWithCoder:`

What I do in that case is to create a method doInitSetup, and call it from both places.

Comment: After I use "self.numberArrayWaitingForCalculate" instead of "_numberArrayWatingForCalculate",there isn't "numberArrayWaitingForCalculate"object when I debug,it's empty. when I use"_numberArrayWatingForCalculate",I can got the "numberArrayWaitingForCalculate"object when debug,through it's "nil"